# asymptotics of Bessel potential with log correction

Tags: real-analysis, special-functions, bessel-functions

Consider the function define by the following Fourier transform:

$$
f(x):= \int \frac{d^nk}{(2\pi)^n} (|k|^2 + m^2)^{-(n+2)/2}  \ln(|k|^2 + m^2)^{-\alpha}  e^{i k\cdot x}
$$

where $x,k\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\alpha\geq 0$.  When $\alpha=0$, $f(x)$ is the standard Bessel potential and
consequently can be expressed as
$$
f(x)= \frac{m^{-2}}{(4\pi)^{n/2} \Gamma\left(\frac{d+2}{2}\right)} (mx) K_1(mx)
$$
where $K_1$ is a modified Bessel function. Consequently, for small $|x|$ one can use the asymptotics $zK_1(z)$ to find the behavior or $f(x)$.

My question is: when $\alpha>0$, what is the the leading order behavior for $|x|\ll 1$ for $f(x)$?

Comment: If $|m| \leq 1$, you need additional conditions on $\alpha$ to make the $\ln$ factor integrable. If $|m| > 1$, the leading term for $f(x)$ is still the non-zero constant $f(0)$, but it doesn't seem to have a nice closed form.